# file.generated.h not found when using a module. Not compiling

Tags: unreal-engine4

I created an unreal module in c++, added it as a dependency to `PrivateDependencyModuleNames`.
I get an error saying one of the generated.h files in primary module could not be found. If I remove new module from the dependencies, then it compiles. Like it is the fact that I am adding a module to dependencies breaks compiling.

This generated file that is supposedly missing is in fact there. There are no file name collisions or anything.

I have tried removing Build, Intermediate, Saved, Binaries folders, regenerating VS files, but no luck.

`Enums.h(7): [C1083] Cannot open include file: 'Enums.generated.h': No such file or directory`

And apparently this is not the only file with this problem. If I remove it, error switches to another file, it’s just a compiler giving me only one error

Comment: `*.generated.h` must be included only if you have a `U*` macro above a `class`, `enum` or `struct`. If your file is plain C++, UHT won't generate this file.

Comment: Yes, error was that I accidentally included a file from primary module in my other module, which shouldn't have been done. This error message is very confusing